# Editing Text Strings within a data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following table

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdFUR.png)

This is the output of my transpose in R. I would like the column with dots to appear like this.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ1hg.png)

What is the best way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Its always recommended to add samples of input and expected output in form of text only in questions, else it will be difficult for people to test their solutions, kindly do edit the same in your question.

Comment: I guess that `gsub()` is the way to go. However, please add samples as the poster above me suggested.

Comment: Try `df$my_column <- sub("\\.{2}", ", ", `df$my_column)` where obviously you need to change `df$my_column` to whatever your data frame and column are called since you didn't include this in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a data frame `a` and the strings being in column 2

```
a[,2] <- gsub("\\.\\.",", ",a[,2])
a[,2] <- gsub("\\."," ",a[,2])
```

should do it.